# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space with Resin and EclipseLink

Tags: eclipse, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, resin, caucho

Ever since I added EclipseLink to my setup I keep getting memory errors every few minutes. It really sucks because Eclipse (IDE) can't even stop resin once that happens and I have to go to the command line to kill it. 
The error is usually this:

```
Unable to load class: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

In my resin.xml I have the following hoping to correct the issue but it doesn't help:

```
<server-default>
    <jvm-arg>-Xmx512m</jvm-arg>
    <jvm-arg>-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m</jvm-arg>
    <jvm-arg>-Xss1m</jvm-arg>
    <jvm-arg>-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled</jvm-arg>
    <jvm-arg>-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled</jvm-arg>
</server-default>
```

The last two lines are the last thing I tried and it failed quickly.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: You can also get the PermGen error if you set your MaxPermSize too high.  1024m works great for me, but if I up it to 4096m I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far a change I made has helped: I put -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m in the Eclipse server launch configuration - vm arguments.

Someone from Caucho told me that when using Eclipse the -X arguments in resin.xml are not used, so that makes sense.